# $h(x) = |g(f(x))|$, then check whether function is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $g(x) = \tan^{–1}|x| – \cot^{–1}|x|$, $f(x)=\dfrac{[x]}{[x+1]}\{x\}$, $h(x) = |g(f(x))|$ where $\{x\}$ denotes fractional part and
$[x]$ denotes the integral part then check whether function is continuous at $x=0$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$h(x)=\left\lvert{\tan^{-1}\dfrac{[x]}{[x+1]}\{x\}}-\cot^{-1}\dfrac{[x]}{[x+1]}\{x\}\right\rvert$$

$$h(0)=\left\lvert{\tan^{-1}\dfrac{0}{1}}-\cot^{-1}\dfrac{0}{1}\right\rvert$$

$$h(0)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

$$h(0^{-})=\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\left\lvert{\tan^{-1}\dfrac{[x]}{[x+1]}\{x\}}-\cot^{-1}\dfrac{[x]}{[x+1]}\{x\}\right\rvert$$

As $x\rightarrow 0^{-}$, $[x]$ will be exactly $-1$, $\{x\}$ will tend to $1$, $[x+1]$ will be exactly $0$

So denominator is exactly zero hence $h(0^{-})$ will be undefined.

But actual answer says that it is continuous at $x=0$
What am I missing here?

Is $\tan^{-1}{\dfrac{1}{0}}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, but how can we say this as $\dfrac{1}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: When we check continuity, if the function is undefined to the left (or the right) of the point we are checking, we only need to show that the right hand (or left hand) limit exists to prove continuity.  e.g. $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is continuous at $0.$

Comment: I think no,  we do that only when either left or right hand of the point is not in the domain

Comment: @DougM, can we say that lim exists at 0?